# How can I override ip address in Universal-analytics?

Tags: node.js, express, universal-analytics

I don't understand where I can override the IP address? This library says you need to set *ipOverride* or *uip*, but it doesn't say where exactly.

```
"universal-analytics": "^0.4.20"
```

My code without overriding the IP address:

```
import ua from 'universal-analytics';

const visitor = ua({
    tid: 'UA-000000004-1',
    cid: '000003b8-0000-4924-9000-00000541eee3'
});

visitor.screenview({
    cd: 'Test screen',
    an: 'Test app'
}).send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't change the user id.

```
const visitor = ua(accountID, user.id);

const ip = headers['x-forwarded-for'];
visitor.set('uip', ip);

const userAgent = headers['user-agent'];
visitor.set('ua', userAgent);

const params = {
  cd: 'Test screen',
  an: 'Test app',
};

const callback = (err: Error | null): void => {
  console.log('screen view err', err);
};

visitor.screenview(params, callback).send()
```